# modify the Description property of an Access table from .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-access, ado.net

I am trying to modify field and table properties for an MS Access database from within a VB.Net project.

So far I have successfully done the following:
1- Retrieve Schema
2- Retrieve Table Descriptions
3- Modify Field Description within a table

I still haven't found a way to modify the Description of a table in the database. I am using ADODB and ADOX.

Below is how I am modifying the field description:

```
    Dim MyDB As New ADOX.Catalog
    Dim MyTable As ADOX.Table
    Dim DB As New ADODB.Connection

    DB.Open("Provider='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';Data Source= 'People.accdb';")
    MyDB.ActiveConnection = DB

    MyTable = MyDB.Tables("People")
    MyTable.Columns("MyID").Properties("Description").Value = "Changed"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Description` property for an Access table is not available to ADOX. You will need to use ACE DAO, like this:

```vb
' required COM reference:
'     Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
' 
' Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao
'
Dim dbe As New DBEngine
Dim db As Database = dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Public\myDatabase.accdb")
Dim tbd As TableDef = db.TableDefs("Donors")
Dim newDescription As String = "This is the new table description."
Try
    tbd.Properties("Description").Value = newDescription
Catch ex As Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
    If ex.ErrorCode = -2146825018 Then
        ' Property not found.
        tbd.Properties.Append(tbd.CreateProperty("Description", DataTypeEnum.dbText, newDescription))
    Else
        Throw
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot